# How do you get a permanent link for Vimeo hosted videos for use in a video sitemap?

Tags: xml-sitemap, video

It seems Vimeo uses video file URLs with tempoary (?) tokens like `https://fpdl.vimeocdn.com/vimeo-prod-example-std-us/0x/xxxx/x/xxxxxxx/xxxxxx.mp4?token=xxxxxxx-0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` in their video embed pages.

I think the token is a temporary key hat makes the video URL time out. Where can I disable the use of tokens?

i.e. how do I do so my video URLs are persistent + public without restrictions? And so i can include hem in video sitemaps?

Answer (score 4):

Well it appears you have 3 options.

**1.**  Determine if the token is a temp token and doesn't expire/change and use it. (Most likely it does; there business model is to get the user to use the embedded player or upgrade account for that support.)

**2**. Use the embed link for the video which of course uses the Vimeo player.

**3**. Which is the correct option/answer for this question and that's to upgrade to a Vimeo PRO account which allows `Third-party player support`. ([source](https://vimeo.com/upgrade))

Comment: Upvoting. The situation is I am helping one generate a video sitemap of a website using Vimeo. In all my pas experiments #1 is temporary/expires. #2 not satisfactory or a least ideal for video sitemaps. #3 best bet - I will try research that way